# How to get the 5 days forecast from OpenWeatherMap using Swift Ui

Tags: swift, swiftui, openweathermap, urlsession, jsondecoder

I´m using OpenWeatherMap api (https://openweathermap.org/forecast5#5days) to make a WeatherApp using swift, i already got the current weather data, but now i want to get the 5 days forecast, how could i do it if i only want to get the list atribute and the list atribute nested to ResponseApi. Please help.

I already tried to make it work, but i failed, makeDataRequestForecast its the function that retrieves the data from the api.

WeatherService

```
import CoreLocation
import Foundation


public final class WeatherService: NSObject {
    
    public let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private let API_KEY = "<api-key>"
    public var completionHandler: ((Weather) -> Void)?
    public var completionHandler2: ((Forecast) -> Void)?

    public override init(){
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
    }
    
    public func loadWeatherData(_ completionHandler: @escaping((Weather)->Void)) {
        self.completionHandler = completionHandler
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    public func loadForecastData(_ completionHandler: @escaping((Forecast)->Void)) {
        self.completionHandler2 = completionHandler
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    //api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&appid={API key}
    
    
    private func makeDataRequestForecast(forCoordinates coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        guard let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=\(coordinates.latitude)&lon=\(coordinates.longitude)&appid=\(API_KEY)&units=metric".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {return}
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, error in
            guard error == nil,let data = data else {return}
        
            
        
            if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastApi.self, from: data) {
                let weatherList = response.list.map { Weather(response: $0) }
                let forecast = Forecast(list: weatherList)
                print(response)
                self.completionHandler2?(forecast)
                print(response)

            }else{
                print("error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    
    private func makeDataRequest(forCoordinates coordinates: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        guard let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=\(coordinates.latitude)&lon=\(coordinates.longitude)&appid=\(API_KEY)&units=metric".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) else {return}
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {return}
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url){ data, response, error in
            guard error == nil,let data = data else {return}
        
        
        if let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseApi.self, from: data){
            let weather = Weather(response: response)
            self.completionHandler?(weather)
        }else{
            print("error")
        }
        }.resume()
    }
}

extension WeatherService: CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    public func locationManager(
        _ manager: CLLocationManager,
        didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
            guard let location = locations.first else {return}
            print("Location \(location.coordinate)")
            makeDataRequest(forCoordinates: location.coordinate)
            makeDataRequestForecast(forCoordinates: location.coordinate)
            
    }
    
    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

struct ForecastApi:Decodable{
    let list:[ResponseApi]
}

struct ResponseApi:Decodable{
    let name:String
    let timezone:Int
    let wind:Wind
    let clouds:Clouds
    let main: MainApi
    let weather:[WeatherApi]
}

struct Wind:Decodable{
    let speed:Double
}
struct Clouds:Decodable{
    let all:Double
}
struct MainApi:Decodable{
    let temp: Double
    let humidity:Int
}

struct WeatherApi : Decodable{
    let description:String
    let icon:String
    
    enum CodingKeys: String,CodingKey{
        case description
        case icon = "main"
        
    }
}
```

Weather

```
import Foundation

public struct Forecast{
    var lista:[Weather]
    
    init(list: [Weather]) {
        lista = list
    }
}

public struct Weather{
    let city:String
    let timezone: String
    let date: String
    let clouds:String
    let wind:String
    let humidity:String
    let temperature:String
    let description:String
    let icon:String
    
    init(response:ResponseApi){
        city = response.name
        timezone = formatSecondsToHours(seconds: response.timezone)
        date = convertToDate(timeZoneOffset: response.timezone)
        clouds = "\(Int(response.clouds.all)) "
        wind = "\(response.wind.speed)"
        humidity = "\(response.main.humidity)"
        temperature = "\(Int(response.main.temp))"
        description = response.weather.first?.description ?? ""
        icon = response.weather.first?.icon ?? ""
    }
}

func formatSecondsToHours(seconds: Int) -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"
    
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(seconds))
    let formattedString = formatter.string(from: date)
    
    return formattedString
}
func convertToDate(timeZoneOffset: Int) -> String {
    let timezone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: timeZoneOffset)
    
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.timeZone = timezone
    dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE, MMMM d yyyy"
    
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    let formattedDateTime = dateFormatter.string(from: currentDateTime)
    
    return formattedDateTime.capitalized
}
```

WeatherViewModel

```
import Foundation

private let defaultIcon = "❌"
private let iconMap = [
    "Drizzle" : "️",
    "ThunderStorm" : "⛈️",
    "Snow" : "❄️",
    "Rain" : "️",
    "Clear" : "☀️",
    "Clouds" : "☁️"
]


class WeatherViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var cityname : String = "City Name"
    @Published var timezone : String = "00:00 __"
    @Published var date : String = "00/00/00"
    @Published var cloudsProb:String = "0 %"
    @Published var humidity:String = "0 %"
    @Published var windSpeed:String = "0 km/h"
    @Published var temperature : String = "__"
    @Published var weatherDescription : String = "__"
    @Published var weatherIcon : String = defaultIcon
    
    public let weatherService: WeatherService
    
    init(weatherService:WeatherService){
        self.weatherService = weatherService
    }
    
    func refresh(){
        weatherService.loadWeatherData{weather in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cityname = weather.city
                self.timezone = weather.timezone
                self.date = weather.date
                self.cloudsProb = "\(weather.clouds) %"
                self.windSpeed = "\(weather.wind) km/h"
                self.humidity = "\(weather.humidity) %"
                self.temperature = "\(weather.temperature)°C"
                self.weatherDescription = weather.description.capitalized
                self.weatherIcon = iconMap[weather.icon] ?? defaultIcon
            }
        }
    }
}

class ForecastViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var lista: [WeatherViewModel] = []

    
    public let weatherService: WeatherService
    
    init(weatherService:WeatherService){
        self.weatherService = weatherService
    }
    
    func refreshForecast(){
        weatherService.loadForecastData { forecast in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [self] in
                    let weatherViewModel = WeatherViewModel(weatherService: self.weatherService)
                    self.lista.append(weatherViewModel)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: "but i failed," Where? What's happening? Is this called `print("error")`? Never use `try?` if you don't know how to debug it! Use `do`/`try`/`catch` and print the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot retrieve the 5 days forecast data from the api because the model structs you have do not **match**
the json data you get from the server. Paste your url into your browser, eg:

```
    https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=44.34&lon=10.99&appid={API key}
```

then copy all of the json data into https://app.quicktype.io/, and all the correct struct models will be created for you.

Adjust them to your purpose, eg, add `Identifiable` and all will work as it does for me in my tests.

Also consult the docs https://openweathermap.org/forecast5#5days, to determine which properties are optionals, and add `?` if required.

Importantly, as mentioned, use `do/try/catch` around your decoding, and print the full error in the `catch`.

For example:

```
 struct ForecastApi: Codable {
     let cod: String
     let message, cnt: Int
     let list: [ListResponse]
     let city: City
 }

 struct City: Codable {
     let id: Int
     let name: String
     let coord: Coord
     let country: String
     let population, timezone, sunrise, sunset: Int
 }

 struct Coord: Codable {
     let lat, lon: Double
 }

 struct ListResponse: Identifiable, Codable {
     let id = UUID()
     let dt: Int
     let main: MainClass
     let weather: [Weather]
     let clouds: Clouds
     let wind: Wind
     let visibility: Int
     let pop: Double
     let sys: Sys
     let dtTxt: String
     let rain: Rain?

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case dt, main, weather, clouds, wind, visibility, pop, sys, rain
         case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
     }
 }

 struct Clouds: Codable {
     let all: Int
 }

 struct MainClass: Codable {
     let temp, feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double
     let pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity: Int
     let tempKf: Double

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case temp
         case feelsLike = "feels_like"
         case tempMin = "temp_min"
         case tempMax = "temp_max"
         case pressure
         case seaLevel = "sea_level"
         case grndLevel = "grnd_level"
         case humidity
         case tempKf = "temp_kf"
     }
 }

 struct Rain: Codable {
     let the3H: Double

     enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
         case the3H = "3h"
     }
 }

 struct Sys: Codable {
     let pod: Pod
 }

 enum Pod: String, Codable {
     case d = "d"
     case n = "n"
 }

struct Weather: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let main: String
    let description: String
    let icon: String
}

 enum Description: String, Codable {
     case brokenClouds = "broken clouds"
     case fewClouds = "few clouds"
     case lightRain = "light rain"
     case moderateRain = "moderate rain"
     case overcastClouds = "overcast clouds"
     case scatteredClouds = "scattered clouds"
 }

 enum MainEnum: String, Codable {
     case clouds = "Clouds"
     case rain = "Rain"
 }

 struct Wind: Codable {
     let speed: Double
     let deg: Int
     let gust: Double
 }
```